# What kind of Activity that passed through ActivityLifecycleCallbacks?

Tags: android, callback, activity-lifecycle

I want to ask if `Activity` parameter in `ActivityLifecycleCallbacks` is always the last top `Activity` or not from the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks.html)?

The reason I ask this question is because, before, I assume the `Activity` parameter always the last top `Activity` that will be shown if I try to show `DialogFragment`, but, I encounter an error that telling me like

**Stack Trace**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed
   at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1450)
   at android.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:687)
   at android.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:663)
   at android.app.DialogFragment.show(DialogFragment.java:230)
   ...
```

**The Code inside Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks**

```
...
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle bundle) {
    Dialog.show(activity.getFragmentManager(), "SHOW DIALOG");
}
...
```

When I try, it always works, when other people try, sometime the app crashed and show the stack trace like above.